# Emitting events to socket.io from PHP

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-redis

Hi I'm trying to emit events from PHP to a socketio server. I've tried both these forks:

https://github.com/rase-/socket.io-php-emitter
https://github.com/ashiina/socket.io-php-emitter

PHP code:

```
<?php

require_once( 'socketio/src/Emitter.php' );

$emitter = new SocketIO\Emitter( array( 'port' => '6379', 'host' => '127.0.0.1') );

$emitter->broadcast->emit( 'testcall', 'data' );

?>
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "Emitter",
    "devDependencies": {
        "express": "~4.13.4",
        "socket.io": "~1.7.3",
        "socket.io-redis": "~4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Node server:

```
var app = require( 'express' )( ),
    http = require( 'http' ).Server( app ),
    io = require('socket.io')( http ),
    redis = require( 'socket.io-redis' );

http.listen( 8081, function( ) {
    console.log( '\n==========================' );
    console.log( 'server listening on *:8081' );
    console.log( '==========================\n' );
});

io.adapter( redis({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }) );

io.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
    socket.on( 'testcall', function( ) {
        console.log( 'testcall' );
    });
});
```

I have redis-cli monitor open and I can see it publishing data to redis but I never see the log appear. I can emit events from a browser but the PHP ones never appear.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works I'm just dumb. The event from PHP is being sent, but to the client not the server. Apparently I forgot how it works hah.

Comment: how? facing the same, not sure how to receive the event client-side